# How to find dma_request_chan() failure reason details?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, xilinx, zynq-ultrascale+

In an external kernel module, using DMA Engine, when calling `dma_request_chan()` returns an error pointer of value -19, i.e. *ENODEV* or "No such device".
Now, in the active device tree, I do find a **dma-names** entry with what I'm trying to get a channel for, so my suspicion is that something else deeper in the forest is already not found.

**How do I find out what's wrong?**

Background:

I have a Zynq MP Ultrascale+ board here, with an FPGA design which uses AXI VDMA block to provide one channel of data to be received on the Cortex A's Linux, where the data is written to DDR4 by the FPGA and to be read from Linux.

I found that there is a Xilinx DMA driver included in the kernel, in the Xilinx source repo anyway, currently kernel version 5.6.0.
And that that driver has no user space interface, such that an intermediate kernel driver is needed.

This is depicted, and they have an example here: [Section "4 DMA Proxy Design"](https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/18842418/Linux+DMA+From+User+Space). I modified the code in the *dma-proxy.c* of the zip file linked there such that it uses only the RX channel, i.e. also only tries to request it.

The code for that is here, to not make this post huge:
[Modified *dma-proxy.c* at onlinegdb.com](https://onlinegdb.com/Hy8VL2-9I)

- Line 407 has the function `create_channel()`, which used to use `dma_request_slave_channel()` which ditches the error code of the function it wraps, so to see the error, I am using that one instead: `dma_request_chan()`.
- The function `create_channel()` is called in function `dma_proxy_probe()` @ line 470 (the occurences before that are deactivated by compile switch).
- So by way of this call, `dma_request_chan()` will be called with the parameters:

  - `create_channel(pdev, &channels[RX_CHANNEL], "dma_proxy_rx", DMA_DEV_TO_MEM);`

The *Device Tree* for my board has an added node for dma-proxy driver as is shown at the top of the *dma-proxy.c*

```dts
dma_proxy {
  compatible ="xlnx,dma_proxy";
  dmas = <&axi_dma_0 0>;
  dma-names = "dma_proxy_rx";
};
```

The name "axi_dma_0" matches with the name in the axi DMA device tree node:

```dts
axi_dma_0: dma@a0000000 {
    #dma-cells = <0x1>;
    clock-names = "s_axi_lite_aclk", "m_axi_s2mm_aclk";
    clocks = <0x3 0x47 0x3 0x47>;
    compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-7.1", "xlnx,axi-dma-1.00.a";
    interrupt-names = "s2mm_introut";
    interrupt-parent = <0x1d>;
    interrupts = <0x0 0x2>;
    reg = <0x0 0xa0000000 0x0 0x1000>;
    xlnx,addrwidth = <0x28>;
    xlnx,sg-length-width = <0x1a>;
    phandle = <0x1e>;

    dma-channel@a0000030 {
        compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-s2mm-channel";
        dma-channels = <0x1>;
        interrupts = <0x0 0x2>;
        xlnx,datawidth = <0x40>;
        xlnx,device-id = <0x0>;
    };
```

If I now look here:

```sh
% cat /proc/device-tree/dma_proxy/dma-names
dma_proxy_rx
```

Looks like my *dma_proxy_rx*, that I'm trying to request the channel for, is in there.

Edit:
In the boot log, I see this:

```
xilinx-vdma a0000000.dma: Please ensure that IP supports buffer length > 23 bits
irq: no irq domain found for interrupt-controller@a0010000 !
xilinx-vdma a0000000.dma: unable to request IRQ 0
xilinx-vdma a0000000.dma: WARN: Device release is not defined so it is not safe to unbind this driver while in use
xilinx-vdma a0000000.dma: Xilinx AXI DMA Engine Driver Probed!!
```

There are warnings - but in the end, the Xilinx AXI DMA Engine got "probed", meaning the lowest level driver loaded and is ready, right?

So it looks to me like there should be my device, but the kernel disagrees.

Comment: Parameters to `dma_request_slave_chan()` doesn't match whatever DMA controller registered.

Comment: Ah, you mean if there's something off in the parameterization, even if the name string is correct, it may yield a "no such device" error? Ok, need to check that in detail...

Comment: Hm, but all dma_request_chan() takes is a pointer to a struct platform_device, which gets passed from probe function and not modified, and then the name string.

Comment: None of DMA engine API takes *struct platform_device*.

Comment: ah sorry, I meant device. The dma-proxy example uses a platform_device and passes the inner device pointer to dma_request_chan.

Comment: Ok, I got the TX/RX loopback test with dma-proxy running, the error was with FPGA config. But found by a guess. Can't answer my question here, as that basically is how to look for / get closer to the root cause, with whatever mechanisms & tools Linux has to offer for this - I still don't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the same problem with similar configuration. After digging a lot of kernel source code (especially drivers/dma/xilinx/xilinx_dma.c) I've solved this problem by changing channel number in `dmas` parameter from 0 to 1 in dma-proxy device tree entry like this:

```
dma_proxy {
  compatible ="xlnx,dma_proxy";
  dmas = <&axi_dma_0 1>;
  dma-names = "dma_proxy_rx";
};
```

It seems that dma-proxy example is written for AXI DMA block with both mm2s (channel #0) and s2mm (channel #1) channels. And if we remove mm2s channel from AXI DMA block, the s2mm channel stays #1.

Comment: It's worth noting that previous versions of the device tree bindings expected (or allowed) the channel to be 0 if only one dma channel was defined.  This has since changed apparently and leaving the channel at 1 resolved the issue for me as well.